# Disable JavaScript in Acrobat Reader for good

Tags: security, pdf, javascript, adobe-reader

For security reasons, I want to disable JavaScript in Acrobat Reader DC in my office.

I [found a registry key](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/javascript.html) (HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\JSPrefs\bEnableJS) that I can deploy via Group Policy which disables JavaScript. So far, so good.

However, once the user opens a PDF file with embedded JavaScript, **Acrobat Reader helpfully offers the user the option to re-enable JavaScript with two simple clicks**:

[image: screenshot]

Is there some way to tell Acrobat Reader (via some registry or group policy settings) that I *really, really* don't want to make it easy for my users to do potentially dangerous stuff?

It's OK for me that they can re-enable JavaScript by digging through Edit/Preferences (even though I'd prefer disabling that as well). But it shouldn't be as easy as clicking on a banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fresh Windows 10 Pro installation with new Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
The following settings no longer work:

"bDisableJavaScript"=dword:00000001

"bDisableTrustedFolders"=dword:00000001

The yellow balloon mentioned is now appearing again despite javascript being turned off in preferences and with the registry settings above. I've confirmed this on 3 workstations so far.

========== **SOLUTION** courtesy of Heinzi ==========

The value name have been changed. It's now "Adobe Acrobat" not "Acrobat Reader".  Here are the *NEW* settings:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\FeatureLockDown]
"bDisableJavaScript"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedFolders"=dword:00000001
```

---

Optional:

```
"bDisableOSTrustedSites"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedSites"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Is it possible that you installed the 64 bit version of Acrobat but still created the keys in HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node? I'm not in front of my PC right now to try it, but I assume that for the 64 bit version of Acrobat you'll have to skip the WOW6432Node.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But I installed the 64-bit version of reader which has been the default for years and I used the correct node: WOW6432Node


From Adobe - These are paths to system level preferences that require administrator permissions to change. Paths vary by platform:
---
Windows 32-bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\(product name)\(version)\FeatureLockDown\
---
Windows 64-bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Adobe\(product name)\(version)\FeatureLockDown\

Comment: You're right. I also use the 64-bit version of Reader, and I also have the registry keys in Wow6432Node - and it works for me. Sorry, can't help here.

Comment: I've also tested it in a virtual machine using the latest Adobe Reader DC.   It is now ignoring these settings. Bummer.

Comment: Hmmm... I also upgraded my Reader (to v2022.003.20258 64 bit) and it still works - JavaScript is still blocked. The yellow bar appears, but the two menu items below "Options" are greyed out, as they should be. Just to make sure: The Options are black in your case?

Comment: The options are not grayed out on a clean install of Acrobat reader with the registry settings.  You can still override with both of the options in the yellow bar!   I use this pdf file to test if JavaScript is enabled or not: Bouncing Button Game - https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Free-Sample-PDF-Files-with-scripts.cfm

Comment: Strange. The exact registry keys set at my system are: Key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown; Value Names: bDisableJavaScript, bDisableOSTrustedSites, bDisableTrustedFolders, bDisableTrustedSites; Values: All REG_DWORD 1.

Comment: 1. Windows Sandbox
2. Install Reader DC from Adobe
3. Disable Javascript in preferences
3. Import:
`code`
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown]
"bDisableJavaScript"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedFolders"=dword:00000001
"bDisableOSTrustedSites"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedSites"=dword:00000001
`code`

4. Test Bouncing Button Game - pdfscripting.com/public/Free-Sample-PDF-Files-with-scripts.cfm

5. Yellow bar appears, select Enable and Javascript Runs overriding the setting. Obnoxious.

Comment: I found it! I dug a bit more in the registry and found that I *also* have those `bDisable*` values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\FeatureLockDown` (note the "Adobe Acrobat" instead of "Acrobat Reader"). I suspect that they changed the name and automatically migrated the settings from the old to the new registry key during some update. If I disable this new key and keep only the old one, JavaScript gets activated on my machine as well.

Comment: Thank You! This resolved the problem  I will add to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the setting in HKLM and not HKCU. Specifically:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockdown\bDisableJavaScript
```

There are quite a few other options for locking different aspects of it down.

FWIW, I am guessing at the key name as I refuse to install their junk on my box.

You can read what I read in the included link and fart around to make sure you got it right.

I gathered this information from [this page](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/JSPrefs.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Setting this option disables the *first* menu entry ("Enable JavaScript ... one time only"). To disable the second entry as well ("Enable JavaScript for this document always"), it's necessary to also set `bDisableTrustedFolders` to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Registry File to Disable Javascript in Acrobat Reader DC:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown]
"bDisableJavaScript"=dword:00000001
"bDisableTrustedFolders"=dword:00000001
```

Or from the command line:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown" /v "bDisableJavaScript" /t REG_DWORD /d "0x00000001" /f

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown" /v "bDisableTrustedFolders" /t REG_DWORD /d "0x00000001" /f
```

Comment: Can you write this is in the form of a commandline `REG ADD`?

Comment: From Command Line:

`reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown" /v "bDisableJavaScript" /t REG_DWORD /d "0x00000001" /f`

`reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown" /v "bDisableTrustedFolders" /t REG_DWORD /d "0x00000001" /f`

Answer (score 0):

Because I notice some confusion about the WOW6432Node ,please see the following clarification:
*The Wow6432Node registry entry indicates that you are running a 64-bit Windows version. The operating system uses this key to display a separate view of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE for 32-bit applications that run on 64-bit Windows versions.*
If you have the 64 bit version, then any changes should happen under the HKLM\Software registry path, unless the application is 64 bit and it is installed under the C:\Program Files (x86) folder or the vendor states to use the Wow6432Node (it may be the case for unknown reasons to me).